# Clear meta.touched in declerative form rules

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I'm using declarative field rules in `react-final-form`, which listen to the change of one field and update the value of another field. The code looks like this:

```
const WhenFieldChanges = ({ field, becomes, set, to }) => (
  <Field name={set} subscription={{}}>
    {(
      { input: { onChange } }
    ) => (
      <OnChange name={field}>
        {value => {
          if (value === becomes) {
            onChange(to)
          }
        }}
      </OnChange>
    )}
  </Field>
)
```

Then it can be used in the form as follows:

```
<WhenFieldChanges
  field="gift"
  becomes={false}
  set="giftMessage"
  to={undefined}
/>
```

It clears the value of the `set` field. But I also need to clear [`meta.touched`](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldRenderProps#metatouched) of that field. How can I do that?

Here is a link to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/52q597j2p).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [`resetFieldState()`](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormApi#resetfieldstate) function on `FormApi` that might do what you want.

[image: Edit React Final Form - Declarative Form Rules]

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thank you very much 